# invariant under t

Tags: measure-theory

Can you help me with this assingment?

Let ($\mathcal X$,$\mathbb E$,µ) be a measure space and $t:(\mathcal X$,$\mathbb E\to \mathcal X, \mathbb E$) is a $\mathbb E-\mathbb E$-measurable function. Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb {R}$ be a non-negative function and let the measure function $\mu: \mathbb {B}_2 \to [0, \infty ]$:
$\mu(B)= \int_B f dm_2$, $B \in  \mathbb B_2$ $\\$. Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $2\times 2$-matrix and $b \in \mathbb{R}^2$. 
$t(\mu)$ has density $t(\mu)=\hat{f} m_2$, where $\hat{f}=\frac {1} {|\det(A)|}f(A^{-1}(x-b))$ I have to show that $\mu$ is invariant under $t (t(µ)=µ)$ if and only if $f(x)= \frac {1}{|\det(A)|}f(A^{-1}(x-b)), x \in \mathbb R^2$

Comment: What are your thoughts on this problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure where to start. Maybe by showing, that the two measures are identical.

Comment: Maybe you can try to solve first the one-dimensional analogue, with $\mathbb R²$ replace by $\mathbb R$.